# How do I create editable bootstrap tables?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table, x-editable

I am using Bootstrap version 5 in my project. Recently in my program I needed my bootstrap table to be editable, meaning the user can change the values of the table cells as desired, the problem is that the x-editable feature Which is already usable in older versions of Bootstrap is not used in newer versions, what library or method do you suggest?

Comment: There's a HTML property called `contenteditable`. Have you ever tried it? <div contenteditable>change me</div>

Comment: What happens when you try to send it as a post/get data?

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways is to install Bootstrap and look in the library to change what is desired but DO NOT change the bootstrap.css file. Instead make a new file that overrides and just in case make sure to put `!important;` at the end of all properties so it works. The reason why I don't suggest changing the bootstrap.css file is because core library files shouldn't be modified. The reason this is is because if you install the library again for some reason then your changes would be deleted.

If this is not what you want, I don't understand your questions.

Or try to add the contenteditable attribute and set it to true